# Computing the matrix representation of the quadratic form $A \mapsto \text{tr}(A^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Define the quadratic form $Q:\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$Q(A) = \text{tr}(A^2).$$ What is the matrix representation of this bilinear form with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ (a $1$ in one entry and $0$ elsewhere)?

If $A = \begin{pmatrix}
w\ \ x \\
y\ \ z
\end{pmatrix}$ then $Q(A) = w^2+2xy+z^2$. I'm struggling to then convert this into a $2\times2$ matrix. I can find a $4\times4$ matrix to represent $Q$, namely $\begin{pmatrix}
1\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\\
0\ \ 0\ \ 1\ \ 0\\
0\ \ 1\ \ 0\ \ 0\\
0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 1
\end{pmatrix}$ but beyond that I'm stuck.

EDIT: My problem arose from question 3.)d.), https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RxCH.png, is this not solvable in its current form then?

Comment: $R^{2\times 2}$ is a 4 dimensional space, so your matrix must have order 4.

Comment: You have the correct matrix.  The $2 \times 2$ matrices form a $4$ dimensional space, so the size of your matrix is correct.

Comment: So am I correct in thinking that 3.)d.) in its current form can not be solved?

http://i.imgur.com/v8UjUVE.png

Comment: @mayhemmelody No, why do you think that? In you're question you're implicitly using the basis in 3(d) already, so it's just a matter of writing your formula for $Q(A)$ using the names of the basis components given in the question.

Comment: @mayhemmelody you *just **solved*** d) in its current form.  Why would you think it can't be solved?  You have the correct $Q$.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that the matrix representation of the quadratic form is $4 \times 4$ whereas the basis elements are $2 \times 2$ matrices. This poses no problem---once one has the quadratic form in hand, one can forget that we usually think of the elements of the vector space as $2 \times 2$ matrices, and simply think of them as elements of some vector space.

Comment: Oh, sorry guys. My confusion came from me thinking that I needed to represent the matrix of the bilinear form in terms of this basis, rather than that just being the basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$.